# Automatically logs out the user upon session expiry

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I am having a Spring roo project that user Spring security for login and logout.My application has got 15 mins timeout. But after 15 mins idle the application is not automatically logging me out and redirecting to login page.
I got the below code in  applicationContextSecurity.xml

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login"/>
```

My application uses Rest services integrated with angular js.
Can someone please help in this?

Comment: Did you used xml based config or java based config ? Did you have any file name `web.xml` ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna   '<session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>'  I do have the configuration in web.xml. My issue with the above is that the session expires but **not automatically redirecting the user to login page**. Do you have any thoughts on the same.